# Scraping Tweets with rtweet from a specific language results ins empty data frame

Tags: r, tweets, rtweet

I just discovered rtweet and I want to get some tweets from a specific language. I tried things like:

```
library(rtweet)
search_tweets("corona","lang:en",n=100,type="popular",include_rts=TRUE)
```

But this results in `data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows`. But this cannot be right. There have to be some tweets about corona recently. Or am I doing something wrong here?

I also tried to recreate examples I found (e.g., this one: https://corpling.hypotheses.org/153), but I wasn't able to do so because I always end up with empty data frames.

I would be happy about suggestions :)

Comment: Maybe I should have said: 'search_tweets("corona",n=100)' works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(rtweet)
library(tidyverse)
tweets <- search_tweets("corona", n = 1000, include_rts = FALSE, lang = "en")
glimpse(tweets)
```

This should work....

Comment: Thank you! This indeed works! :) :) Sadly, the geo_coords are all NA.